# Having trouble sending and receiving an Asset from Android Wear to handheld

Tags: android, google-api, wear-os

I'm trying to send an asset from an Android wear device to a handheld and am having trouble with either setting up the DataRequest or when retrieving it. I'm not sure exactly where the error lies.

Here's my 'send to data layer' code on the wear device:

```
PutDataMapRequest request = PutDataMapRequest.create("/audio");
request.getDataMap().putAll(data); //data is a DataMap with a timestamp asset, and an audio asset called "audioAsset"

PendingResult<DataApi.DataItemResult> pendingResult = Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(googleClient, request.asPutDataRequest().setUrgent());

pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() { ... }
```

So that's how I put the DataMap into a request and send it, and I've checked the datamap contains the correct assets and data.

On the handheld, when onDataChanged is called, I do this:

```
@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {

    DataMap dataMapReceived;

    for (DataEvent event : dataEvents) {

        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED &&
                event.getDataItem().getUri().getPath().equals("/audio")) {

            dataMapReceived = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem()).getDataMap();
            Asset audioAsset = dataMapReceived.getAsset("audioAsset");
            Log.d("H_AUDIO", "Audio Bytes Length: " + audioAsset.getData().length); // Crashes here with null pointer
        }
```

The program crashes with a null pointer exception when I try to access 'audioAsset.getData().length', so I'm maybe not retrieving the asset in the correct way. Can anyone tell me if I'm going about this the wrong way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to transfer binary data like that, it is recommended to use either an [Asset](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/assets.html) or [ChannelApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/ChannelApi). I suggest you review the documentation to see what technology is preferred for the task that you have in mind. In addition, it might be easier for you to use libraries that wrap a number of apis in an easy-to-use interface such as [WearCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearCompanionLibrary).

Comment: I am already using an Asset. The trouble I'm having is putting that into a data map and retrieving it at the other end

Comment: It pays off if you pay attention to the details; you are doing request.getDataMap().putAll(data) while for assets, if you look through the link I gave you, it should be added by: request.getDataMap().putAsset("some_name", asset)